# transfer 3d model processing from Xna to Android?

Tags: xna, android

I developed an XNA scenario in a desktop application and I need to make the same scenario in an Android app so I need to process data on the desktop computer and just display it in Android app using socket programming. For now, I can just transfer text from my desktop app to the android app, but how can I transfer a 3D model from XNA to Android? The model format is FBX.

Answer (score 1):

FBX is a common interchange format, so ideally just need to find a library or framework on Android that supports loading them. Alternatively, convert the FBX files to some other format that your Android framework or libraries can load.

If you don't current have any investment into a particular API on Android, and

- you want to just load the FBX files directly: search Google for "Android FBX loading API" or similar terms, evaluate the features of the resulting technologies against the rest of your needs, and choose one.
- you want to convert the FBX files to something else: first choose the 3D graphics framework you're going to use on Android, then search Google for tools for converting FBX files to any of the formats supporting by your chosen 3D graphics framework's import pipeline.